# Jshowoff slider in wordpress

Tags: javascript, animation, slider

I want to add in my home page (Wordpress) sliders that appears when I click on the image of category.
For example, when I click on Nutrition, i want to show a slide that contains last posts of this category. I have 4 categories so I must have a slider for each one
For that, I use this code, jshowoff.js:

```js
$ = jQuery;

(function($){$.fn.jshowoff=function(settings){var config={animatePause:true,autoPlay:true,changeSpeed:600,controls:true,controlText:{play:'Play',pause:'Pause',next:'Next',previous:'Previous'},effect:'fade',hoverPause:true,links:true,speed:3000};if(settings)$.extend(true,config,settings);if(config.speed<(config.changeSpeed+20)){alert('jShowOff: Make speed at least 20ms longer than changeSpeed; the fades aren\'t always right on time.');return this;};this.each(function(i){var $cont=$(this);var gallery=$(this).children().remove();var timer='';var counter=0;var preloadedImg=[];var howManyInstances=$('.jshowoff').length+1;var uniqueClass='jshowoff-'+howManyInstances;var cssClass=config.cssClass!=undefined?config.cssClass:'';$cont.css('position','relative').wrap('<div class="jshowoff '+uniqueClass+'" />');var $wrap=$('.'+uniqueClass);$wrap.css('position','relative').addClass(cssClass);$(gallery[0]).clone().appendTo($cont);preloadImg();if(config.controls){addControls();if(config.autoPlay==false){$('.'+uniqueClass+'-play').addClass(uniqueClass+'-paused jshowoff-paused').text(config.controlText.play);};};if(config.links){addSlideLinks();$('.'+uniqueClass+'-slidelinks a').eq(0).addClass(uniqueClass+'-active jshowoff-active');};if(config.hoverPause){$cont.hover(function(){if(isPlaying())pause('hover');},function(){if(isPlaying())play('hover');});};if(config.autoPlay&&gallery.length>1){timer=setInterval(function(){play();},config.speed);};if(gallery.length<1){$('.'+uniqueClass).append('<p>For jShowOff to work, the container element must have child elements.</p>');};function transitionTo(gallery,index){var oldCounter=counter;if((counter>=gallery.length)||(index>=gallery.length)){counter=0;var e2b=true;}
else if((counter<0)||(index<0)){counter=gallery.length-1;var b2e=true;}
else{counter=index;}
if(config.effect=='slideLeft'){var newSlideDir,oldSlideDir;function slideDir(dir){newSlideDir=dir=='right'?'left':'right';oldSlideDir=dir=='left'?'left':'right';};counter>=oldCounter?slideDir('left'):slideDir('right');$(gallery[counter]).clone().appendTo($cont).slideIt({direction:newSlideDir,changeSpeed:config.changeSpeed});if($cont.children().length>1){$cont.children().eq(0).css('position','absolute').slideIt({direction:oldSlideDir,showHide:'hide',changeSpeed:config.changeSpeed},function(){$(this).remove();});};}else if(config.effect=='fade'){$(gallery[counter]).clone().appendTo($cont).hide().fadeIn(config.changeSpeed,function(){if($.browser.msie)this.style.removeAttribute('filter');});if($cont.children().length>1){$cont.children().eq(0).css('position','absolute').fadeOut(config.changeSpeed,function(){$(this).remove();});};}else if(config.effect=='none'){$(gallery[counter]).clone().appendTo($cont);if($cont.children().length>1){$cont.children().eq(0).css('position','absolute').remove();};};if(config.links){$('.'+uniqueClass+'-active').removeClass(uniqueClass+'-active jshowoff-active');$('.'+uniqueClass+'-slidelinks a').eq(counter).addClass(uniqueClass+'-active jshowoff-active');};};function isPlaying(){return $('.'+uniqueClass+'-play').hasClass('jshowoff-paused')?false:true;};function play(src){if(!isBusy()){counter++;transitionTo(gallery,counter);if(src=='hover'||!isPlaying()){timer=setInterval(function(){play();},config.speed);}
if(!isPlaying()){$('.'+uniqueClass+'-play').text(config.controlText.pause).removeClass('jshowoff-paused '+uniqueClass+'-paused');}};};function pause(src){clearInterval(timer);if(!src||src=='playBtn')$('.'+uniqueClass+'-play').text(config.controlText.play).addClass('jshowoff-paused '+uniqueClass+'-paused');if(config.animatePause&&src=='playBtn'){$('<p class="'+uniqueClass+'-pausetext jshowoff-pausetext">'+config.controlText.pause+'</p>').css({fontSize:'62%',textAlign:'center',position:'absolute',top:'40%',lineHeight:'100%',width:'100%'}).appendTo($wrap).addClass(uniqueClass+'pauseText').animate({fontSize:'600%',top:'30%',opacity:0},{duration:500,complete:function(){$(this).remove();}});}};function next(){goToAndPause(counter+1);};function previous(){goToAndPause(counter-1);};function isBusy(){return $cont.children().length>1?true:false;};function goToAndPause(index){$cont.children().stop(true,true);if((counter!=index)||((counter==index)&&isBusy())){if(isBusy())$cont.children().eq(0).remove();transitionTo(gallery,index);pause();};};function preloadImg(){$(gallery).each(function(i){$(this).find('img').each(function(i){preloadedImg[i]=$('<img>').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));});});};function addControls(){$wrap.append('<p class="jshowoff-controls '+uniqueClass+'-controls"><a class="jshowoff-play '+uniqueClass+'-play" href="#null">'+config.controlText.pause+'</a> <a class="jshowoff-prev '+uniqueClass+'-prev" href="#null">'+config.controlText.previous+'</a> <a class="jshowoff-next '+uniqueClass+'-next" href="#null">'+config.controlText.next+'</a></p>');$('.'+uniqueClass+'-controls a').each(function(){if($(this).hasClass('jshowoff-play'))$(this).click(function(){isPlaying()?pause('playBtn'):play();return false;});if($(this).hasClass('jshowoff-prev'))$(this).click(function(){previous();return false;});if($(this).hasClass('jshowoff-next'))$(this).click(function(){next();return false;});});};function addSlideLinks(){$wrap.append('<p class="jshowoff-slidelinks '+uniqueClass+'-slidelinks"></p>');$.each(gallery,function(i,val){var linktext=$(this).attr('title')!=''?$(this).attr('title'):i+1;$('<a class="jshowoff-slidelink-'+i+' '+uniqueClass+'-slidelink-'+i+'" href="#null">'+linktext+'</a>').bind('click',{index:i},function(e){goToAndPause(e.data.index);return false;}).appendTo('.'+uniqueClass+'-slidelinks');});};});return this;};})(jQuery);(function($){$.fn.slideIt=function(settings,callback){var config={direction:'left',showHide:'show',changeSpeed:600};if(settings)$.extend(config,settings);this.each(function(i){$(this).css({left:'auto',right:'auto',top:'auto',bottom:'auto'});var measurement=(config.direction=='left')||(config.direction=='right')?$(this).outerWidth():$(this).outerHeight();var startStyle={};startStyle['position']=$(this).css('position')=='static'?'relative':$(this).css('position');startStyle[config.direction]=(config.showHide=='show')?'-'+measurement+'px':0;var endStyle={};endStyle[config.direction]=config.showHide=='show'?0:'-'+measurement+'px';$(this).css(startStyle).animate(endStyle,config.changeSpeed,callback);});return this;};})(jQuery);


jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#bttjshowoffslider').jshowoff({
     animatePause: true, // Whether to use 'Pause' animation text when pausing
     autoPlay: true, // Whether to start playing immediately
  changeSpeed: 600, // Speed of transition in milliseconds
  controls: true, // Whether to create & display controls (Play/Pause, Previous, Next) 
  controlText:{play:'Play',pause:'Pause',previous:'&#8249; Previous',next:'Next &#8250;'}, // Text to use for controls
  cssClass: 'bttjshowoff', // Add an additional custom class to the .jshowoff wrapper
  effect: 'slideLeft', // Type of transition effect: 'fade', 'slideLeft' or 'none'
  hoverPause: true, // Whether to pause on hover
  links: false, // Whether to create & display numeric links to each slide
  speed: 3000 // Time each slide is shown in milliseconds
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="bttjshowoffslider">

   <!-- Slide 1 Started -->
   <div><p>The first content</p></div>
   <!-- Slide 1 End -->
   
   <!-- Slide 2 Started -->
   <div>
     
      <h2>HTML Slide</h2>
      <p>Example of an HTML slide.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam.</p>
   </div>
   <!-- Slide 2 End -->
   
   <!-- Slide 3 Started -->
   <div><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9kaEeWmMii8/U1cvTJnsqzI/AAAAAAAAIgo/yRYms2nwYo0/s1600/slide-image-3.jpg"/></div>
   <!-- Slide 3 End -->
   
   <!-- Slide 4 Started -->
   <div><p>The last content</p></div>
   <!-- Slide 4 End -->
   
</div>
```

But with this code, i can't control the animation. how can I do it??
I hope that i was clear.